# In QGraphicsView's wheelEvent, self.scale does not allow self.scrollContentsBy to work

Tags: python, pyqt5, scale, pyside2, qgraphicsview

Both of the **scale** and **scroll** for the content of a `QGraphicsView` applied to the `wheelEvent`.
The problem is scroll only works if there is no **scale** on the `wheelEvent`.
No success with applying `self.update()` between **scale** and **scroll** call.

**Extra points and guesses**
If comment out the **scroll part**, **scale** works exact and on its place without displacement of view with scrolling up and down multiple times but with **scroll part** not commented out, with multiple scrolling (multiple zoom in and out) a little displacement of view has been obsereved.
It seems there is a conflict of fireing methods that call ui elements.

*Appreciate your share of knowledge*

```
# importing libraries
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
import sys

class Scene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, _scene_width, _scene_height):
        super(Scene, self).__init__()
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, _scene_width, _scene_height)
        map_center = _scene_width / 2
        te = QTextEdit()
        te.insertPlainText("Test Text")
        te.setGeometry(map_center, map_center, 100, 100)
        self.addWidget(te)


class View(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, _scene_width, _scene_height):
        super(View, self).__init__()
        self.scale_factor = 1
        self.scene_width = _scene_width
        self.scene_height = _scene_height
        scene = Scene(_scene_width, _scene_height)
        self.setScene(scene)
        self.showMaximized()

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if self.underMouse():

            # scale part which doesn't let the scroll part to work
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                self.scale_factor = self.scale_factor * 1.2
                self.scale(1.2, 1.2)
            else:
                self.scale_factor = self.scale_factor / 1.2
                self.scale(1 / 1.2, 1 / 1.2)

            # scroll part which works fine if the scale part is commented out
            self.scrollContentsBy(10, 0) # values are just for testing


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = View(1000000, 1000000)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The technical problem is that when `scale()` is called, the view needs some time to update itself, but the real problem is that you should not use `scrollContentsBy()` at all, as the [documentation reports]: "Calling this function in order to scroll programmatically is an error". If you want to scroll the view, you must use the scroll bars or `centerOn()`. Also, consider that using the wheel event to both scale *and* scroll is not a very good choice, as it makes the behavior unintuitive; maybe you want to ensure that the scaling moves the view in a specific point?

Comment: @musicamante Thank you. `centerOn()` worked fine.

Comment: Note that if you're just trying to zoom on the mouse cursor, you can just use [`setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#transformationAnchor-prop).

Comment: @musicamante Yes, I wanted to zoom on the mouse cursor, and using `setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)` is a direct predefined solution but a problem still exists which is after multiple zoom in and out, displacement (zoom is not exactly on the mouse position) is noticable which is a problem in my case senario. Maybe there some other facts that one has to consider too to be able to have an exact zoom on the cursor by using **transformation anchor**? For now, `centerOn()` works fine and with some math the exact point of zoom has been achieved. It was very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You could try to store the transformation matrix within each zoom in, and eventually restore it when zooming out, but if you want a more precise answer I'd suggest you to create a new question, as its scope is a bit different than this one.